# How can I get the Handle for the active control using Interop

Tags: c#, user-controls, interop

If a window has an active control, example and open combobox, can i then get a handle to that control using Iterop? The active control is not in managed code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Pinvoke - [User32.GetFocus()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetFocus.html). Maybe this is what you want.

See also: [MSDN GetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646294%28VS.85%29.aspx), read the remarks

Comment: It really didt sound like what i needed, but it doesnt seem to work, I have a combobox open, and GetFocus() returns 0

Comment: Read the MSDN Documentation for details, I added the link to my post